# Simulation of a Pendulum hanging on a spinning Disk

Tags: python, validation, math, sympy

Can anybody get this code to run? I know, that it is very long and maybe not easy to understand, but what I am trying to do is to write a simulation for a problem, that I have already posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4876146/pendulum-hanging-on-a-spinning-disk

I try to make a nice simulation, that would look like the one someone answered the linked question with. The picture in the answer is written in mathematica and I had no idea how to translate it.
Hope you can help me finish this up.

There are two elements of code. One calculating the ODE second degree and one plotting it 3 times. When you plot the ODE, you can see, that the graph line is not doing, what it is supposed to.
I don't know, where the mistake is but hopefully you can help.

Here are the two snippets:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from IPython.display import display
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def FindDGL():
    N = CoordSys3D('N')
    e = N.i + N.j + N.k
    t = sp.symbols('t')

    x = sp.symbols('x')
    y = sp.symbols('y')
    z = sp.symbols('z')

    x = sp.Function('x')(t)
    y = sp.Function('y')(t)
    z = sp.Function('z')(t)

    p = x*N.i + y*N.j + z*N.k

    m = sp.symbols('m')
    g = sp.symbols('g')
    r = sp.symbols('r')
    omega = sp.symbols('omega')
    q0 = sp.symbols('q0')
    A = sp.symbols('A')
    l = sp.symbols('l')
    
    
    xl = sp.symbols('xl')
    yl = sp.symbols('yl')
    zl = sp.symbols('zl')

    dpdt = sp.diff(x,t)*N.i + sp.diff(y,t)*N.j + sp.diff(z,t)*N.k
    
    #Zwang = ((p-q)-l)
    Zwang = (p.dot(N.i)**2*N.i +p.dot(N.j)**2*N.j +p.dot(N.k)**2*N.k - 2*r*(p.dot(N.i)*N.i*sp.cos(omega*t)+p.dot(N.j)*N.j*sp.sin(omega*t))-2*q0*(p.dot(N.k)*N.k) + r**2*(N.i*sp.cos(omega*t)**2+N.j*sp.sin(omega*t)**2)+q0**2*N.k) - l**2*N.i - l**2*N.j -l**2*N.k
   
    display(Zwang)

    dpdtsq = dpdt.dot(N.i)**2*N.i + dpdt.dot(N.j)**2*N.j + dpdt.dot(N.k)**2*N.k
    
    #La = 0.5 * m * dpdtsq - m * g * (p.dot(N.k)*N.k) + (ZwangA*A)

    L = 0.5 * m * dpdtsq + m * g * (p.dot(N.k)*N.k) - Zwang*A

    #display(La)
    display(L)
    
    Lx = L.dot(N.i)
    Ly = L.dot(N.j)
    Lz = L.dot(N.k)

    Elx = sp.diff(sp.diff(Lx,sp.Derivative(x,t)), t) + sp.diff(Lx,x)
    Ely = sp.diff(sp.diff(Ly,sp.Derivative(y,t)), t) + sp.diff(Ly,y)
    Elz = sp.diff(sp.diff(Lz,sp.Derivative(z,t)), t) + sp.diff(Lz,z)

    display(Elx)
    display(Ely)
    display(Elz)

    ZwangAV = (sp.diff(Zwang, t, 2))/2
    display(ZwangAV)
    ZwangA = ZwangAV.dot(N.i)+ZwangAV.dot(N.j)+ZwangAV.dot(N.k)
    display(ZwangA)

    Eq1 = sp.Eq(Elx,0)
    Eq2 = sp.Eq(Ely,0)
    Eq3 = sp.Eq(Elz,0)
    Eq4 = sp.Eq(ZwangA,0)

    LGS = sp.solve((Eq1,Eq2,Eq3,Eq4),(sp.Derivative(x,t,2),sp.Derivative(y,t,2),sp.Derivative(z,t,2),A))
    #display(LGS)
    #display(LGS[sp.Derivative(x,t,2)].free_symbols)
    #display(LGS[sp.Derivative(y,t,2)].free_symbols)
    #display(LGS[sp.Derivative(z,t,2)])
    XS = LGS[sp.Derivative(x,t,2)]
    YS = LGS[sp.Derivative(y,t,2)]
    ZS = LGS[sp.Derivative(z,t,2)]
    
    #t_span = (0, 10)
    dxdt = sp.symbols('dxdt')
    dydt = sp.symbols('dydt')
    dzdt = sp.symbols('dzdt')
    #t_eval = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    XSL = XS.subs({ sp.Derivative(y,t):dydt, sp.Derivative(z,t):dzdt, sp.Derivative(x,t):dxdt, x:xl , y:yl , z:zl})
    YSL = YS.subs({ sp.Derivative(y,t):dydt, sp.Derivative(z,t):dzdt, sp.Derivative(x,t):dxdt, x:xl , y:yl , z:zl})
    ZSL = ZS.subs({ sp.Derivative(y,t):dydt, sp.Derivative(z,t):dzdt, sp.Derivative(x,t):dxdt, x:xl , y:yl , z:zl})
    #display(ZSL.free_symbols)
    XSLS = str(XSL)
    YSLS = str(YSL)
    ZSLS = str(ZSL)
    replace = {"xl":"x","yl":"y","zl":"z","cos":"np.cos", "sin":"np.sin",}
    for old, new in replace.items():
        XSLS = XSLS.replace(old, new)
    for old, new in replace.items():
        YSLS = YSLS.replace(old, new)
    for old, new in replace.items():
        ZSLS = ZSLS.replace(old, new)
    return[XSLS,YSLS,ZSLS]


Result = FindDGL() 
print(Result[0])
print(Result[1])
print(Result[2])
```

Here is the second one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def Q(t):
    omega = 1 
    return r * (np.cos(omega * t) * np.array([1, 0, 0]) + np.sin(omega * t) * np.array([0, 1, 0])) + np.array([0, 0, q0])

def equations_of_motion(t, state, r, omega, q0, l):
    x, y, z, xp, yp, zp = state
    dxdt = xp
    dydt = yp
    dzdt = zp
    dxpdt = dxdt**2*r*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - dxdt**2*x/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + 2.0*dxdt*omega*r**2*np.sin(omega*t)*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - 2.0*dxdt*omega*r*x*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + dydt**2*r*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - dydt**2*x/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - 2.0*dydt*omega*r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + 2.0*dydt*omega*r*x*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + dzdt**2*r*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - dzdt**2*x/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + g*q0*r*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - g*q0*x/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - g*r*z*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + g*x*z/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + omega**2*r**2*x*np.cos(omega*t)**2/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + omega**2*r**2*y*np.sin(omega*t)*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - omega**2*r*x**2*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - omega**2*r*x*y*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    dypdt = dxdt**2*r*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - dxdt**2*y/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + 2.0*dxdt*omega*r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - 2.0*dxdt*omega*r*y*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + dydt**2*r*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - dydt**2*y/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - 2.0*dydt*omega*r**2*np.sin(omega*t)*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + 2.0*dydt*omega*r*y*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + dzdt**2*r*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - dzdt**2*y/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + g*q0*r*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - g*q0*y/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - g*r*z*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + g*y*z/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + omega**2*r**2*x*np.sin(omega*t)*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + omega**2*r**2*y*np.sin(omega*t)**2/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - omega**2*r*x*y*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - omega**2*r*y**2*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    dzpdt = dxdt**2*q0/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - dxdt**2*z/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + 2.0*dxdt*omega*q0*r*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - 2.0*dxdt*omega*r*z*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + dydt**2*q0/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - dydt**2*z/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - 2.0*dydt*omega*q0*r*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + 2.0*dydt*omega*r*z*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + dzdt**2*q0/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - dzdt**2*z/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - g*r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - g*r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + 2.0*g*r*x*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + 2.0*g*r*y*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - g*x**2/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - g*y**2/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + omega**2*q0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + omega**2*q0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - omega**2*r*x*z*np.cos(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - omega**2*r*y*z*np.sin(omega*t)/(q0**2 - 2.0*q0*z + r**2*np.sin(omega*t)**2 + r**2*np.cos(omega*t)**2 - 2.0*r*x*np.cos(omega*t) - 2.0*r*y*np.sin(omega*t) + x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    return [dxdt, dydt, dzdt, dxpdt, dypdt, dzpdt]

r = 0.5  
omega = 1.2  
q0 =  1 
l = 1  
g = 9.81

#{x[0] == r, y[0] == x'[0] == y'[0] == z'[0] == 0, z[0] == q0 - l}
initial_conditions = [r, 0, 0, 0, 0, q0-l] 

tmax = 200
solp = solve_ivp(equations_of_motion, [0, tmax], initial_conditions, args=(r, omega, q0, l), dense_output=True)#, method='DOP853')

t_values = np.linspace(0, tmax, 1000)
p_values = solp.sol(t_values)
print(p_values.size)

d =0.5

Qx = [Q(ti)[0] for ti in t_values]
Qy = [Q(ti)[1] for ti in t_values]
Qz = [Q(ti)[2] for ti in t_values]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 16))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(p_values[0], p_values[1], p_values[2], color='blue')
ax.scatter(r, 0, q0-l, color='red')
ax.plot([0, 0], [0, 0], [0, q0], color='green') 

ax.plot(Qx, Qy, Qz, color='purple')
#ax.set_xlim(-d, d)
#ax.set_ylim(-d, d)
#ax.set_zlim(-d, d)
ax.view_init(30, 45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Helping you run your entire codebase is not what Stackoverflow is for. If the code you wrote doesn't run (or doesn't run as expected) for you, then it's up to you to drill down into where in the code things first start to go wrong, based on knowing what the code _should_ do given some input, and what you start seeing it do instead (either immediately or after a while) and then focus your investigation on that _part_ of the code, because thing start to go wrong on a single line of code: find that line. Even if the subsequent lines may _also_ have problems. You'll find those next.

Comment: I am sorry for providing my entire code base, but the question is half about the ODE, that it produces, half about the Plotting for visualisation. Where is the missing link between the right Lagrangian and the wrong Simulation in 3D space. The code does run and the Question is why does the Simulation look wrong. Maybe this question belongs on the maths stack exchange but I wanted to try and ask people here.

Comment: As it stands @Mo711 your code is so complex that it is uncheckable. It is not even clear that the underlying equations are correct. In the link to Stack Exchange one answer includes the much better suggestion of using two polar angles. It is better to use 2 degrees of freedom than 3 generalised coordinates with a separate constraint. (Note that you may want to rework the 2-angle solution there, as the angles used are not actually those suggested.) With that 2-angle approach it is straightforward to code this in Python. But, sadly, the thread is closed.

Comment: @lastchance let's find one more person to cast a vote to reopen this question!

Comment: @Davide_sd, yes it would be good to get it reopened: it was a fascinating problem and the animation is good in Python. Unfortunately, I’m still short of enough reputation to cast a vote to reopen.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans please, need one more vote to reopen this question. This question is significant, because sympy's mechanics module is very powerful, but very difficult to use. As a matter of fact, many questions about this topic never gets answered. At this moment, there are potentially 2 people that can offer a solution to this question, which would definitely offer a lot of insights into simulations with sympy.

Comment: very well, you should be able to write an answer now. But this post [still needs improving](/help/how-to-ask) because as written the question is "can anyone get this to run", which is _not_ what SO is for.  @Mo711 please update the post a little to explain the actual _code_ problem you're having, which line(s) you think things are going wrong on, and where, based on what debugging and (re)searching you already did, Because you're not posting for yourself. You're posting for yourself _and_ anyone else with the same problem in the future, and they need to be able to tell you had their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited** to include the direct solution in Cartesians, since this was the original direction taken by the OP. See the bottom of this answer.

[image]

@Mo711, your code (particularly the second sample) is just too long to check. Lagrangian mechanics is straightforward to apply – if you choose the right generalized coordinates.

This is a 2-degree-of-freedom problem (so your first post on Stack Exchange must be wrong: it only has 1). In my opinion it's unnatural to use 3 cartesian coordinates and then have to apply a constraint because they aren't independent. Instead, as suggested by one of the responders to your Stack-Exchange post I would use two angles. The analysis below leads to equations similar to the angular equations in the SE reply, but not quite the same: I think he/she was taking angle θ from the horizontal rather than the angle from the downward vertical that I use below.

First the Lagrangian equations.

Let ϕ be the angle between the vertical plane containing the string and the x-axis. Let θ be the angle made by the string with the downward vertical. Then the coordinates of the bob (relative to the centre of the ring) are:

[image]

Differentiate with respect to time and we get velocity components

[image]

Summing, squaring and simplifying using trig formulae:

[image]

The Lagrangian (strictly, Lagrangian divided by mass, but mass would cancel in the analysis that follows) is

[image]

whence

[image]

From the Lagrangian equations for a conservative system

[image]

we get (after a LOT of algebra!) the key equations for our degrees of freedom:

[image]

The code sample below solves these using `solve_ivp`. Note that the denominator of the second equation means that you shouldn’t start with the pendulum vertical, as sin⁡θ would be 0.

Then your animation.

I use `FuncAnimation` from matplotlib.animation. The objective here is to update any elements of your plot (in this case the ends of the pendulum string) in each frame. The code plots an animation by default, but you can remove the subsequent comment to store it as a (rather large) graphics file.

If you want the trajectory rather than the animation then re-comment the commands at the bottom to choose `plot_figure` instead.

Note that the system is chaotic and very sensitive to the relative sizes of disk and pendulum and the angular velocity ω. If I do a dimensional analysis, the trajectory shape should be a function of g/ω^2 L (or the ratios of the periods of the disk and the stand-alone pendulum), R/L, and the initial angles.

**CODE**

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

g = 9.81

def plot_animation( t, qx, qy, qz, x, y, z ):
   plotInterval = 1
   fig = plt.figure( figsize=(4,4) )
   ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d' )
   ax.view_init(30, 45)
   ax.set_xlim( -1.0, 1.0 );   ax.set_ylim( -1.0, 1.0 );   ax.set_aspect('equal')

   ax.plot( qx, qy, qz, 'k' )                                            # ring
   a = ax.plot( [qx[0],x[0]], [qy[0],y[0]], [qz[0],z[0]], 'g' )          # pendulum string
   b = ax.plot( [x[0]], [y[0]], [z[0]], 'ro' )                           # pendulum bob
   def animate( i ):
      a[0].set_data_3d( [qx[i],x[i]], [qy[i],y[i]], [qz[i],z[i]] )       # update anything that has changed
      b[0].set_data_3d( [x[i]], [y[i]], [z[i]] )
   ani = animation.FuncAnimation( fig, animate, interval=4, frames=len( t ) )
   plt.show()
#  ani.save( "demo.gif", fps=50 )


def plot_figure( qx, qy, qz, x, y, z ):
   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
   ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
   ax.plot( qx, qy, qz, 'k' )                                                  # disk
   ax.plot( x, y, z, 'b' )                                                     # bob trajectory
   ax.plot( ( qx[-1], x[-1] ), ( qy[-1], y[-1] ), ( qz[-1], z[-1] ), 'g' )     # final line
   ax.plot( x[-1], y[-1], z[-1], 'ro' )                                        # final bob
   ax.view_init(30, 45)
   ax.set_xlim( -1.0, 1.0 );   ax.set_ylim( -1.0, 1.0 );   ax.set_aspect('equal')
   plt.show()



def deriv( t, Y, R, omega, L ):
    theta, phi, thetaprime, phiprime = Y
    ct, st = math.cos( theta ), math.sin( theta )
    phase = omega * t - phi
    thetaprime2 = ( phiprime ** 2 * L * st * ct + omega ** 2 * R * ct * math.cos( phase ) - g * st ) / L
    phiprime2   = ( -2 * thetaprime * phiprime * L * ct + omega ** 2 * R * math.sin( phase ) ) / ( L * st )
    return [ thetaprime, phiprime, thetaprime2, phiprime2 ]



R = 0.5
omega = 2.0
L = 1.0

Y0 = [ 0.01, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0 ]
period = 2 * np.pi / omega
tmax = 5 * period
solution = solve_ivp( deriv, [0, tmax], Y0, args=(R,omega,L), rtol=1.0e-6, dense_output=True )

t = np.linspace( 0, tmax, 1000 )
Y = solution.sol( t )
theta = Y[0,:]
phi   = Y[1,:]

# Position on disk
qx = R * np.cos( omega * t )
qy = R * np.sin( omega * t )
qz = np.zeros_like( qx )

# Trajectory
x = qx + L * np.sin( theta ) * np.cos( phi )
y = qy + L * np.sin( theta ) * np.sin( phi )
z =    - L * np.cos( theta )

#plot_figure( qx, qy, qz, x, y, z )
plot_animation( t, qx, qy, qz, x, y, z )
```

**Trajectory:**
[image]

If you absolutely must do the problem in Cartesian coordinates (and I strongly advocate that you don’t) then you can vastly simplify the solution given in Stack Exchange. The Lagrangian is

[image]

where x is the location of the bob and "q"=(R cos⁡ωt,R sin⁡ωt,0). The three Lagrangian equations, rewritten in vector form give

[image]

λ must be found from the constraint equation

[image]

Differentiating twice, and noting that

[image]

together with the expression for the acceleration above, gives the expression for 2λ below. Thus, your equation set is

[image]

This is far simpler than the expression given in Stack Exchange, but probably equivalent. It is shown in code below. The only real difference from the first code is the routine deriv(), since you now have different dependent variables.

The other problem with a constrained Lagrangian is that the initial conditions (position and velocity) must satisfy both the constraint equation AND its derivative. i.e. the string length is L and it is not initially lengthening.

**Code with Cartesian dependent variables.**

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

g = 9.81

def plot_animation( t, qx, qy, qz, x, y, z ):
   plotInterval = 1
   fig = plt.figure( figsize=(4,4) )
   ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d' )
   ax.view_init(30, 45)
   ax.set_xlim( -1.0, 1.0 );   ax.set_ylim( -1.0, 1.0 );   ax.set_aspect('equal')

   ax.plot( qx, qy, qz, 'k' )                                            # ring
   a = ax.plot( [qx[0],x[0]], [qy[0],y[0]], [qz[0],z[0]], 'g' )          # pendulum string
   b = ax.plot( [x[0]], [y[0]], [z[0]], 'ro' )                           # pendulum bob
   def animate( i ):
      a[0].set_data_3d( [qx[i],x[i]], [qy[i],y[i]], [qz[i],z[i]] )       # update anything that has changed
      b[0].set_data_3d( [x[i]], [y[i]], [z[i]] )
   ani = animation.FuncAnimation( fig, animate, interval=4, frames=len( t ) )
   plt.show()
#  ani.save( "demo.gif", fps=50 )


def plot_figure( qx, qy, qz, x, y, z ):
   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
   ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
   ax.plot( qx, qy, qz, 'k' )                                                  # disk
   ax.plot( x, y, z, 'b' )                                                     # bob trajectory
   ax.plot( ( qx[-1], x[-1] ), ( qy[-1], y[-1] ), ( qz[-1], z[-1] ), 'g' )     # final line
   ax.plot( x[-1], y[-1], z[-1], 'ro' )                                        # final bob
   ax.view_init(30, 45)
   ax.set_xlim( -1.0, 1.0 );   ax.set_ylim( -1.0, 1.0 );   ax.set_aspect('equal')
   plt.show()



def deriv( t, Y, R, omega, L ):
    x, y, z, xdot, ydot, zdot = Y
    qx, qy = R * math.cos( omega * t ), R * math.sin( omega * t )
    qxdot, qydot = -omega * R * math.sin( omega * t ), omega * R * math.cos( omega * t )
    twoLambda = ( g * z + ( R ** 2 - qx * x - qy * y ) * omega ** 2 - ( xdot - qxdot ) ** 2 - ( ydot -qydot ) ** 2 - zdot ** 2 ) / L ** 2
    xddot = twoLambda * ( x - qx )
    yddot = twoLambda * ( y - qy )
    zddot = twoLambda * z - g
    return [ xdot, ydot, zdot, xddot, yddot, zddot ]



R = 0.5
omega = 2.0
L = 1.0

Y0 = [ R, 0.0, -L, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
period = 2 * np.pi / omega
tmax = 5 * period
solution = solve_ivp( deriv, [0, tmax], Y0, args=(R,omega,L), rtol=1.0e-6, dense_output=True )

t = np.linspace( 0, tmax, 1000 )
Y = solution.sol( t )
x = Y[0,:]
y = Y[1,:]
z = Y[2,:]

# Position on disk
qx = R * np.cos( omega * t )
qy = R * np.sin( omega * t )
qz = np.zeros_like( qx )

#plot_figure( qx, qy, qz, x, y, z )
plot_animation( t, qx, qy, qz, x, y, z )
```